# module 'plotting' has no attribute 'EpisodeStats'

Tags: python, plot, attributes, reinforcement-learning

Im writing a Q-Learning RL code form my own custom environment, but I faced with this error in my code (**module 'plotting' has no attribute 'EpisodeStats'**) This is my Q-Learning code:

```
pip install plotting
import itertools 
import pandas as pd 
from collections import defaultdict 
import json
import numpy as np
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers.core import Dense
from keras.optimizers import sgd
from FooEnv import FooEnv
import random
import sys 
sys.setrecursionlimit(10**6)
import time
import os
import matplotlib
from collections import namedtuple
from collections import deque, namedtuple
import plotting 
matplotlib.style.use('ggplot')

real_time_info = [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
start = [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0,1.0]
env = FooEnv(start,real_time_info)
num_actions=17
num_episodes=1000

def createEpsilonGreedyPolicy(Q, epsilon, num_actions): 
    """ 
    Creates an epsilon-greedy policy based 
    on a given Q-function and epsilon. 

    Returns a function that takes the state 
    as an input and returns the probabilities 
    for each action in the form of a numpy array  
    of length of the action space(set of possible actions). 
    """
    def policyFunction(state): 

        Action_probabilities = np.ones(num_actions, 
                dtype = float) * epsilon / num_actions 

        best_action = np.argmax(Q[state]) 
        Action_probabilities[best_action] += (1.0 - epsilon) 
        return Action_probabilities 

    return policyFunction


def qLearning(env, num_episodes, discount_factor = 1.0, 
                            alpha = 0.6, epsilon = 0.1): 
    """ 
    Q-Learning algorithm: Off-policy TD control. 
    Finds the optimal greedy policy while improving 
    following an epsilon-greedy policy"""

    # Action value function 
    # A nested dictionary that maps 
    # state -> (action -> action-value). 
    Q = defaultdict(lambda: np.zeros(env.action_space.n)) 

    # Keeps track of useful statistics 
    stats = plotting.EpisodeStats( 
        episode_lengths = np.zeros(num_episodes), 
        episode_rewards = np.zeros(num_episodes))    

    # Create an epsilon greedy policy function 
    # appropriately for environment action space 
    policy = createEpsilonGreedyPolicy(Q, epsilon, env.action_space.n) 

    # For every episode 
    for ith_episode in range(num_episodes): 

        # Reset the environment and pick the first action 
        state = env.reset() 

        for t in itertools.count(): 

            # get probabilities of all actions from current state 
            action_probabilities = policy(state) 

            # choose action according to 
            # the probability distribution 
            action = np.random.choice(np.arange( 
                    len(action_probabilities)), 
                    p = action_probabilities) 

            # take action and get reward, transit to next state 
            next_state, reward, done, _ = env.step(action) 

            # Update statistics 
            stats.episode_rewards[ith_episode] += reward 
            stats.episode_lengths[ith_episode] = t 

            # TD Update 
            best_next_action = np.argmax(Q[next_state])  
            td_target = reward + discount_factor * Q[next_state][best_next_action] 
            td_delta = td_target - Q[state][action] 
            Q[state][action] += alpha * td_delta 

            # done is True if episode terminated 
            if done: 
                break

            state = next_state 

    return Q, stats
```

This is a code that I found in the Internet, and I think it should work perfectly. But I have this error in this line:

```
    **module 'plotting' has no attribute 'EpisodeStats'**

stats = plotting.EpisodeStats( 
            episode_lengths = np.zeros(num_episodes), 
            episode_rewards = np.zeros(num_episodes))
```

It would be greatly appreciated if you could advice me.

Comment: Is plotting a custom class or is it some standard library? Could you add the link to the file which has the plotting class?

Answer (score 0):

Same problem.
Then l found this version of [plotting.py](https://github.com/dennybritz/reinforcement-learning/blob/master/lib/plotting.py) from github.
After replaceing the original plotting.py with this one, that fixed.

Comment: Why should we need to edit third party lib?

Comment: According to the error discription, there must be something mismatch in package "plotting" bewteen enviroments since the demo code works in [original posts](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/q-learning-in-python/). So we need to find a version of "plotting" with attribute 'EpisodeStats', which is the right one we need for this demo code rather than the default we get from "pip install plotting".

Answer (score 0):

`*args,`

search for this code in your plotting.py file and cut it form the code

should look like this

```
_warn_if_gui_out_of_main_thread()
return _backend_mod.show(**kwargs)
```

worked for me

Comment: Why should we need to edit third party lib?